# Newly built Chevy 350 won't start

Tags: starting, chevrolet, suburban, sbc

I've just completed rebuilding my Suburban's 350 into a 383, and feels/sounds so, so close, and I'm not 100% sure what I'm missing yet. I think it might be just not getting fuel, but then I did some reading about people having the distributor put in 180 degrees off of the cam (or the crank, I'm not sure), which causes backfiring out of the intake, which seems like what might have happened when we tried to use our starting fluid.

I've actually got a video of us trying to turn it over here [in this link](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipP-tybHNvfF6axxeDy3CvGo7GxWshFtD0l1ktbKS0-HQD4yRtrR9swlAA--_hANqg/photo/AF1QipNWuMks7Q9mRl9LT09pSBN6eVc58f4uQnsp3fhQ?key=WjYwd0dfdmpNTUN0Y0k5Y1RTOHR0U1plY0pKZEd3).

Does this sound like just not getting fuel? Or does it sound like I might have that 180 problem, or both?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like it's getting fuel, first off. Things to check:

- You don't state the year, so I don't know if this has a mechanical pump or an electric one. Ensure the carb is getting fuel. As long as it is a carb, fill up the float bowls through the vent tube.
- If this is fuel injected (throttle body), you'll need to put a fuel pressure gauge on the Schrader valve. If FI, you should also be hearing the fuel pump run. (I can't quite tell if it's FI or carb'd from the video and you don't mention this). If you're not getting fuel pressure at the Schrader, check to ensure you haven't blown the fuse for the fuel pump.

Second thing is, it sounds like the timing is off. It could be either 180° out (doubtful from how it sounded with ether), or you might have your wires out of order (more probable in my mind):

- Double/triple check to ensure your wires are on there correctly. The firing order for *most* Gen I SBC's is 1-8-4-3-6-5-7-2 ... When you check each lead, follow it *completely* to the end ... don't make assumptions.
- Ensure the distributor rotor is pointing to the #1 cylinder at TDC.

  - Pull the #1 spark plug, place your thumb over the hole, then have someone bump the starter a little at a time until a large rush of compression comes out the hole. Look at the timing mark on the harmonic damper and bring it all the way to TDC (0° to the timing mark).
  - Pull the distributor cap off, noting position of the #1 spark plug lead. Normally, this is located at about the 5 O'Clock position:

[image]

More than likely, both of these things (fire & fuel) are at issue with your trying to get it to start.

Comment: 1999 Suburban, my bad! The engine is the 350 Vortec L31

Comment: And thank you, you're fantastic, I will dive into the engine again once I get home :)

Comment: So follow for the throttle body instructions. The distributor should still be the same.

Comment: Getting an engine to TDC can also be done by rotating gently with a spanner (without plugs fitted) and using a welding rod or similar to « see » the piston movement until you get close to the timing marks.

Comment: So I wasn't getting fuel, but I definitely am now (I can now smell gas up by the engine), and I checked the timing it seems to be exactly correct, but still not starting. I don't think I'm getting any spark, so I'll need to get a check light and make sure the ignition is all working I guess

Comment: If you were getting *something* when using starting fluid, I'd suggest you have spark. Pull the #1 spark plug wire off of the plug, stuff a long #2 Phillips head screwdriver into the boot, then hold the shaft of the screwdriver near some bare metal. Have someone crank the engine. You should see/hear spark.

Comment: @SolarMike - That isn't *exactly* right. It will just show you TDC, not when TDC on the compression stroke (well, 50/50 chance). You need to be at TDC between compression and exhaust strokes or your timing will be 180° out.

Comment: @Paulster2 Agreed, but if you take the oil cap off, on many engines you can see if the valves are moving ie one closing / one opening or both are closed which does tell you exactly which part of the cycle you are on if you know the cycle - worked on all the 4 cylinder engines, v6 and v8 that I worked on... Of course, some engines don't have timing marks on the harmonic damper, they are on the flywheel rim with an inspection panel...

Comment: @SolarMike - Sure, but why would you want to unseal a sealed engine to figure this out, when pulling the spark plug and putting your thumb over the hole would give you the *correct* information to begin with? Why create more work when you don't have to? My suggested method works, is easy, and doesn't create any unneeded work for yourself.

Comment: @Paulster2 Don't you put oil in through the Oil Cap hole? Or you fill the sump then bolt it up?? I don't find removing the oil cap too onerous or difficult... If you think I meant removing the valve or rocker covers... then that's different.

Comment: @SolarMike - Most SBC engines *you can't see* the #1 rockers through the oil cap fill hole, so the only way to see them is by removing the valve cover. That's what's onerous as compared to removing the spark plug.

Comment: Comments are not for elongated conversations. If you'd like to continue this discourse, please let me know in [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Comment: Alright so I've been messing with this car straight since posting this question, and I've learned quite a bit. You're right it's not getting fuel (fuel pressure is 64psi), there's good spark (tested ignition coil with spark tester, sparks like mad (and shocked the hell out of me lol)), but the injectors aren't pulsing

Comment: Turns out it was likely a security problem (security light was on). So I got a bypass chip, security light immediately went away, got a scanner, "PCM/VCM VTD Fail Enab" is "No", "VTD Auto Learn Timer" is "Inactive", "VTD Fuel Dis Ign Off" is "No" and "VTD Fuel Disable" is "Inactive", so I think security problems are done with, but injectors still wont fire :(

Comment: The injectors are firing like randomly though (and super infrequent), and the scanner shows "Valid Reference Pulse" as "No" mostly, but "Yes" when I do get random pulses. I figured this might indicate a bad cam sensor, replaced it, nothing changed though, so now I'm going to try putting my old dist in (maybe the bracket under the rotor isn't being read by the sensor?)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Turns out it wasn't getting fuel, or spark actually. Looks like the PCM might have actually been the culprit, sending spark signals out randomly, even with all sensor testing well going into the PCM. Instead of replacing the PCM, we swapped the injectors for a carb (and an HEI dist) and the thing fired right up