# 1999 Chevy Suburban 5.7 - What is "Valid Reference Pulse"

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-injectors

Searching google for that exact text in quotes (what the scanner shows) yields basically no results. What does it refer to?

For some context that lead to this question, I'm not getting my injectors to fire, but I cam getting good spark, and this "Valid Reference Pulse" shows "No", most of the time; the injectors DO fire, but rarely and randomly, and when they do, "Valid Reference Pulse" switches to "Yes" (but only for that second or so).

My distributor is new, and I've also replaced the cam sensor that it came with, but this hasn't changed the behavior. Also, my `SECURITY` light is off. The scanner shows no codes on the Engine, or OBDII, just a code about the ABS.

Previous maybe somewhat related question that got me to this point
[Newly built Chevy 350 won't start](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/62438/newly-built-chevy-350-wont-start/62444?noredirect=1#comment109144_62444)

Comment: Maybe a bad crankshaft sensor and or sensor ring.

Comment: @Moab so before this we weren't getting any spark, either, but I replaced the crank sensor and we got perfect spark afterwards, on all plugs

Comment: Its something else then, will it start while cranking and shooting some brake or carb cleaner in the intake?

Comment: @Moab It tries to (not sure if starting fluid is enough to get it going though), and I have the upper intake off right now and I've been testing the injectors with a noid light

Comment: @Moab the injectors have power, and they're definitely capable of firing (as they fire randomly), but the ECM just isn't telling the injectors to open at a regular pace, and I can't figure out why not

Comment: You have good fuel pressure? Somewhere around 65psi?

Comment: @Moab yup, 64 PSI with key on (first try), drops to 60 with key off

Comment: The ECM compares the existance and the timing the crank signal and the cam signal.Then it determines which crank signal is TDC for plug #1. That is the "valid reference pulse." If either signal is intermittent or unstable, the ECM cannot start the fuel and spark operation. Check the sensor wiring and connectors.

Comment: @JohnCanon Previously I have replaced the cam sensor on the new dist (it also came with a new one), and also last night I swapped my new distributor for the old one (including its original cam sensor) and all 3 cam sensors have the same behavior. I also followed the wires back to the ECM and I couldn't find any that were grounding/looked damaged

Comment: The sensor in the distributor is not the cam sensor, it is the hall effect sensor which detects the spinning reluctor. The camshaft sensor is on the front of the engine. Check this link:  https://itstillruns.com/1999-suburban-camshaft-sensor-installation-7476889.html

Comment: @JohnCanon I don't think that's correct, the body style of the Chevy trucks changed in 1999, *except* for the Suburban. It still has the older body style. That article links to a manual for the body style after this one

Comment: @JohnCanon and I do have good spark at all the spark plugs

Comment: What scanner are you using? Do you have a scope? Can you verify the crank signal and cam signal?

Comment: @Ben I'm using a Bosch 1350, and I'm not sure what you mean by scope, but there's nothing I've seen in the scanner so far that would indicate that they're describing the crank or cam signal.

Comment: By scope I mean an Oscilloscope. You'd want to backprobe the two sensors and verify that they have a good pattern. You also say the security light is off but is the PCM showing fuel enabled during cranking?

Comment: @Ben I don't own one of those (I'll get one on the way home). But I have "VTD Fuel Disable: Inactive; VTD Fuel Dis Ign Off: No; VTD Auto Learn Timer: Inactive; PCM/VCM VTD Fail Enab: No", I think those are all the ones related to security (although that last one is sort of vague, I'm not sure whether or not "No" is good or bad) on the scanner

Comment: IIRC The CKP 4x signal is the reference pulse referred to by the PID on your scantool. The CMP signal is used for misfire strategy. If you truly have spark all the time but no injector pulse I'd backprobe an injector and verify you have power all the time and that the VCM can command the injector. The VTD PIDS look normal make sure the values don't change while cranking. If "Valid Reference Pulse" is showing no most of the time I would think that there is a problem with the CKP sensor wiring or the VCM.

Comment: @Ben got it, that makes sense, I did some further testing with spark and I think that might be the issue, probably because I have missing ground straps, I installed two of them last night but I didn't have a second person to crank while I checked the spark

Comment: @Ben Uh so we're taking a different direction and swapping the injectors with a carb, it's already stroked and is now a 383, so now it will just also be carbed

Comment: @Ben, well, it runs now lol. It's carbureted now instead of fuel injected (swapped the intake), and also the distributor was also swapped to an old style HEI one, and the car started up first try. Sadly that won't help anyone else with the same issue, but at least mine is now working